# What language should I choose to make web focused bots? (to parse, cross-check...)

Tags: web, scripting, bots

wonderful community here :)

I'm getting into programming and my main interest right now is making a bot to automate cross checking of web products and prices across different web platforms like ebay, amazon, etc.

What language do you suggest is the best for that purpose? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have more details? Are you planning on doing this in a browser extension? Are you crawling websites?

Comment: @Jersh Hey! Thank you for the reply :) Not really, just a bot to compare prices and products.

The idea is to parse the product names and prices and cross check their prices between different shop platforms.

Comment: Where are planning on running it?

Comment: Whatever is better @Jersh